# Android Studio / Archivo drawable xml para personalizar Edit Text

Tags: android, edittext

Quiero modificar la underline de un EditText y lo unico que conseguí fue este código:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     >
     <item 
         android:state_pressed="true"
         android:drawable="@android:drawable/edittext_pressed" 
         /> <!-- pressed -->    
     <item 
         android:state_focused="true"
         android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_focused_blue" 
         /> <!-- focused -->    
     <item 
         android:drawable="@android:drawable/edittext_normal" 
         /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

El problema es que lo único que hace este código es poner un drawable dentro de la vista el cual contiene una figura (shape) de tipo linea la cual se sitúa en el centro del editText. Como puedo modificar este código para lograr que solamente la underline del editText cambie?

Comment: Ponle android:backgroundTint="@color/white" al edittext property

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero no funciona. Me sale el siguiente mensaje: attribute backgroundtint is only used in api level 21 and higher (current min is 16)

Comment: eso es porque tu version minima de android es 16, puedes crear un xml para las mayores de 21 y ya no te dara problemas

Comment: Hermano, muchísimas gracias. Ya cambié la versión y tu código me funciona. Muy amable por la ayuda!!!!. Te hago la última pregunta. Por que estando en una versión sdk 16, el IDE me reconoce la propiedad backgroundTint pero no la aplica, y en  cambio, en una versión sdk 22, el IDE la reconoce y la aplica?

Comment: El significado de cambiar esa version de "16" "21" se traduce en las versiones de Android osea 4.01 para la 16 o para la 21 de 5.0 + info aqui https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Historial_de_versiones_de_Android

Comment: Hoy en dia es muy dificil que los celulares no tengo almenos version 5.0 pero si quieres que aun asi se puedan instalar en versiones mas viejas, solamente crea 2 xmls uno con la propiedad nnueva y la anterior que la ignore, depende lo que necesites

Comment: Y el porque no funciona para apis mas viejas es porque el SO de android no lo admite

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/TintableBackgroundView Aqui tienes la doc oficial

Comment: Buenísimo. Entendí todo perfectamente. En serio que estoy muy agradecido Bruno. Tu tiempo me fue muy útil. Cierro esta pregunta!!!